# Radio Button Project with null point errors

Tags: java

How do i fix it?

-------------------Configuration: Questions - JDK version 1.8.0_25  - -------------------- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Question3.(Question3.java:103) at Question2.(Question2.java:51) at Questions.main(Questions.java:17)

//////////////\
This is the output of the whole program

Hey i need some help with my project, but i really don't know how to fix it. I'm really new at this, thanks in advance for helping.

This is the first class, it is named Questions

```js
/**
 * @(#)Questions.java
 *
 * Questions application
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/22
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
 
public class Questions {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     Question2 frame = new Question2();
     frame.setSize(800,600);
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This is the 2nd class, it is name Question2

```js
/**
 * @(#)Question2.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/22
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Question2 extends JFrame {
 
 private JPanel buttonpanel;

    public Question2() {
     JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
     JMenu menu=new JMenu();
     JMenuItem FileExit=new JMenuItem();
     JMenuItem reset=new JMenuItem();
     setJMenuBar(menuBar);
     menu.setText("File");
     FileExit.setText("Reset");
     
     menu.add(FileExit);
     menu.add(FileExit);
     menuBar.add(menu);
     
     setTitle("How to use Radio Buttons");
     
     reset.addActionListener(new ResetListener());
     
     FileExit.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener (){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Question2.this.windowClosed();
       }
      }
     );
     
     this.addWindowListener
      (
       new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
         
        Question2.this.windowClosed();
       }
       }
       );
       
       buttonpanel=new Question3();
       buttonpanel.setSize(250,400);
       this.add(((Question3)buttonpanel).get_panel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
    
    protected void windowClosed(){
     System.exit(0);
    }
    
    private class ResetListener implements ActionListener
    {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {
      
      ((Question3)buttonpanel).reset(new Question2());
       setVisible(true);
      
     }
    }
    
    
}
```

This is the 3rd class, it is named Question3

```js
/**
 * @(#)Question3.java
 *
 *
 * @author 
 * @version 1.00 2015/5/22
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Question3 extends JPanel {
 
 private JPanel primary;
 private JRadioButton button1;
 private JRadioButton button2;
 private JRadioButton button3;
 private JRadioButton button4;
 private JLabel question1;
 private JLabel question2;
 private JLabel question3;
 private JLabel question4;
 private JLabel question5;
 private JLabel question6;
 private JLabel question7;
 private JLabel question8;
 private JLabel question9;
 private JLabel question10;
 private JRadioButton [][] Array1;
 private JLabel [][] Arrayq;

    public Question3() {
     /*
     Array1 = new JRadioButton[10][4];
     Array1[1][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Mesopotamian Civilization");
     Array1[1][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Egyptian Civilization");
     Array1[1][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Harrapan Civilization");
     Array1[1][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Chinese Civilization");
     
     Array1[2][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Mesopotamian Civilization");
     Array1[2][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Egyptian Civilization");
     Array1[2][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Harappan Civilization");
     Array1[2][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Chinese Civilization");
     
     Array1[3][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. China");
     Array1[3][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. India");
     Array1[3][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Irag");
     Array1[3][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Egypt");
     
     Array1[4][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Aeschylus");
     Array1[4][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Sophocles");
     Array1[4][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Aristophanes");
     Array1[4][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Philip");
     
     Array1[5][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. 776 BC");
     Array1[5][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. 780 BC");
     Array1[5][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. 790 BC");
     Array1[5][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. 800 BC");
     
     Array1[6][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Euclid");
     Array1[6][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Pythagoras");
     Array1[6][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Hippocrates");
     Array1[6][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Erastosthenes");
     
     Array1[7][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. 1000 BC");
     Array1[7][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. 1200 BC");
     Array1[7][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. 1400 BC");
     Array1[7][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. 1600 BC");
     
     Array1[8][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Cicero");
     Array1[8][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Seneca");
     Array1[8][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Lucretius");
     Array1[8][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Octavian");
     
     Array1[9][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. Tacitus");
     Array1[9][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. Plinky");
     Array1[9][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. Virgil");
     Array1[9][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. Marcus");
     
     Array1[10][0]=new JRadioButton ("A. 1285-90");
     Array1[10][1]=new JRadioButton ("B. 1288-93");
     Array1[10][2]=new JRadioButton ("C. 1290-96");
     Array1[10][3]=new JRadioButton ("D. 1295-1301");
     */
     //arrayq declaring
     /*
     Arrayq = new JLabel[10][1];
     Arrayq[1][0]=new JLabel ("1. Rivers Tigris and Euphrates are associated with?");
     Arrayq[2][0]=new JLabel ("2. Which is considered as oldest civilization of the world?");
     Arrayq[3][0]=new JLabel ("3. Which among following is called \"Gift of the Nile\"?");
     Arrayq[4][0]=new JLabel ("4. Who is considered as the master of Greek comedy?");
     Arrayq[5][0]=new JLabel ("5. When ancient Olympic games first held?");
     Arrayq[6][0]=new JLabel ("6. Who is known as the father of Modern Medicine?");
     Arrayq[7][0]=new JLabel ("7. Rome was founded around?");
     Arrayq[8][0]=new JLabel ("8. Which was not an Roman Philosopher?");
     Arrayq[9][0]=new JLabel ("9. Who was among the famous Roman poets?");
     Arrayq[10][0]=new JLabel ("10. Marco Polo, Venetian traveller, travelled from Venice to China and Japan in:");
     */
     //question declaring
     primary=new JPanel();
     primary.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));
     //font assigning
     question1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question3.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question4.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question5.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question6.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question7.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question8.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question9.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     question10.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
     //button assigning
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Mesopotamian Civilization",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Egyptian Civilization",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Harrapan Civilization",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Chinese Civilization",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Mesopotamian Civilization",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Egyptian Civilization",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Harappan Civilization",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Chinese Civilization",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. China",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. India",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Irag",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Egypt",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Aeschylus",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Sophocles",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Aristophanes",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Philip",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. 776 BC",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. 780 BC",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. 790 BC",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. 800 BC",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Euclid",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Pythagoras",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Hippocrates",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Erastosthenes",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. 1000 BC",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. 1200 BC",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. 1400 BC",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. 1600 BC",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Cicero",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Seneca",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Lucretius",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Octavian",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. Tacitus",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. Plinky",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. Virgil",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. Marcus",false);
     
     button1=new JRadioButton("A. 1285-90",false);
     button2=new JRadioButton("B. 1288-93",false);
     button3=new JRadioButton("C. 1290-96",false);
     button4=new JRadioButton("D. 1295-1301",false);
     //array assigning
     question1=new JLabel("1. Rivers Tigris and Euphrates are associated with?");
     question2=new JLabel("2. Which is considered as oldest civilization of the world?");
     question3=new JLabel("3. Which among following is called \"Gift of the Nile\"?");
     question4=new JLabel("4. Who is considered as the master of Greek comedy?");
     question5=new JLabel("5. When ancient Olympic games first held?");
     question6=new JLabel("6. Who is known as the father of Modern Medicine?");
     question7=new JLabel("7. Rome was founded around?");
     question8=new JLabel("8. Which was not an Roman Philosopher?");
     question9=new JLabel("9. Who was among the famous Roman poets?");
     question10=new JLabel("10. Marco Polo, Venetian traveller, travelled from Venice to China and Japan in:");
     button1.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
     button1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
     button1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
     button1.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
     primary.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
     primary.add(question1);
     primary.add(question2);
     primary.add(question3);
     primary.add(question4);
     primary.add(question5);
     primary.add(question6);
     primary.add(question7);
     primary.add(question8);
     primary.add(question9);
     primary.add(question10);
     //primary.add(button1);
     //primary.add(button2);
     //primary.add(button3);
     //primary.add(button4);
     
     QuestionListener1 listener1 = new QuestionListener1();
     button1.addActionListener(listener1);
     button2.addActionListener(listener1);
    }
    public JPanel get_panel(){
     return primary;
    }
    public void reset(JFrame frame){
     question1.setText("Which move is better?");
     button1.setSelected(false);
     button2.setSelected(false);
     
     frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void array1(){
    }
    
    private class QuestionListener1  implements ActionListener 
     {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
      
      if(event.getSource()==button1){
       question1.setText("I love vanilla too");
      }
      if(event.getSource()==button2){
       question1.setText("Don't get chocolate on your shirt");
      }
     }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Don't put your error stack trace in the comments. Edit your post and add it there.

Comment: My question is how do i run it, please i don't know a lot about this, i don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Your `//font assigning` section needs to come after your `//array assigning` section in `Question3.java`.  Simply move that block of code down to after the line starting with `question10=new JLabel("10. M` and it should run.

Until `//array assigning` assigns variables to each of the `question#` variables they're all null, so trying to call `question1.setFont(...)` before assigning a `JLabel` to `question1` throws a `NullPointerException` like you saw.